# Java Using Netbeans - Entity Class from database

Tags: java, model-view-controller, netbeans

what exactly entity class from database does?
how can i take the advantage of it?

i'm going to make an app for my project using MVC pattern, the app will use database.
i need some clue.

Comment: See [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-Relational_Mapping)

Comment: Also see [Persistence with JavaEE](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/partpersist.htm#BNBPY)